# How do I convert time in nanoseconds to date type in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am inserting data from a csv into Elasticsearch 5.2 through Logstash 5.2. My date is stored as a number in nanoseconds in the csv. Elasticsearch only takes date in milliseconds. When I tried inserting in nanoseconds, the resulting date was from far into the future. How do I convert this into milliseconds and then insert it?

```
input {
    http {
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => "|"
        columns => ["logEntryTimeNano", "ip", "country", "state", "city"]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1"]
        index => "log"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your problem arises with the trailing 3 digits of the nanotime, you can simply write a ruby filter to remove those digits this way :

```
filter {
    csv{
        separator => ","
        columns => ["logEntryTimeNano", "ip", "country", "state", "city"]
    } ruby {
        code => "event.set('[logEntryTimeNano]', event.get('logEntryTimeNano')[0..-4])"
    }   
}
```

Comment: Should there be square brackets covering `logEntryTimeNano` in ruby code?

Comment: @khateeb  As long as it is a single field, it is ok not to have square brackets, if you want to access nested field (let's fay foo.bar) you would have to write `[foo][bar]` (mandatory). See the logstash event api for more details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutate/gsub to remove last 6 numbers (considering your number is composed of 9 numbers).

```
mutate {
    gsub => ["logEntryTimeNano", "\d{6}$", ""]
}
```

You can also take a look on [date_nanos](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/date_nanos.html) if you use Elasticsearch 7, since this version already supports nanoseconds.